# Show that v is an eigenvector of A and find the corresponding eignvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that v is an eigenvector of A and find the corresponding eignvalue

A= [image]

v= [image]

A*v = [-12 -60] = -12[1 5] = -12*v

So I was wondering, if the eignvalue is 12 or -12? From my calculations I got the answer to be -12 but after looking online, it looks like I might be wrong and it could be 12.

This is pretty basic but any advice would be great

Thanks

Comment: According to your computation, $Av = -12\frac{1}{2}v$... So the eigenvalue would be $-6$. Didn't check your computation, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalue is $-6$, not $-12$. You rearranged things incorrectly. The eigenvalue equation is $Av=\lambda v$ so if you find a pair $v$ and $\lambda$ satisfying that equation, $v$ is an eigenvector and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. There is another eigenvalue: $\lambda = 3$ so $12$ cannot be an eigenvalue. What made you think $12$ was also an eigenvalue?

(The easy way to see that $-3$ is also an eigenvalue is that the determinant of a matrix is just the product of the eigenvalues; alternatively, the trace is just the sum of the eigenvalues.)

Comment: But if we look at Wolfram: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B4%2C-2%7D%2C%7B5%2C-7%7D%7D*%7B%7B2%7D%2C%7B10%7D%7D

He says that it is 12

Comment: It says the eigenvalues are $-6$ and $3$. Are you reading it correctly?

Comment: If I multiply A*v, I can factor 12

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B4%2C-2%7D%2C%7B5%2C-7%7D%7D.%7B%7B2%7D%2C%7B10%7D%7D

Comment: But then that's no longer $v$. When you factor the $-12$, you have $Av = -12\left(\begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 5\end{array}\right)$. This is not of the proper form because $\left(\begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 5\end{array}\right)\neq \left(\begin{array}{r} 2 \\ 10\end{array}\right)$.